# Array not counting objects in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, int

Curious as to why this is not working?

```
@IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel! <-- Outlet/var


let array : [Int] = [1,2,3]

self.counterLabel.text = array.capacity
```

I am getting the error below and I was wondering anybody knew how to fix this? I am trying to get the text label to display the number of objects in the array.

> Cannot assign a value of type 'Int' to a value of type 'String?'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting a value of type String with a value of type Int so you need to convert the Int to a String:

```
self.counterLabel.text = String(array.count)
```

As commenters have mentioned, the property you're looking for is count

Comment: this won't solve the problem because he is accessing the wrong property. He should be using String(array.count)

Comment: I was using count but tried out capacity but I got a value of 4 with only 3 objects in the array. But that solution did work for me, I just replaced capacity with count.

Comment: Can also do "\\(array.count)"